# Select 15 elements from 1 million row data in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 1 million row data in my sql how do i QUERY effeciently and fastly TO TAKE N ELEMENTS FROM SQL SERVER 
here is my code

```
  select  * from Persons where Id in 
    (select top 10 ID from Persons order by newid())
```

is it good? or you another option?

Comment: i don't know what newid() is, but 1 million rows is nothing. depends on the db engine though, but as long as you have an index on ID and whatever newid() touches, such a query should run in milliseconds. the golden rule is quite simple: all columns that are touched in the ``where`` clause shall be part of an index - in the best case even part of the _same_ index.

If you can reduce the columns needed to select (``*`` in general is not a good idea) you can even put the select-columns in the index to the db engine can retrieve your result without touching the table at all. lightning fast.

Comment: It would help what you actually trying to achieve. Also the code you have seem to be more complicated than what is described in the question - some clarification why you chose that could be nice too. Please [edit] the question with those details.

Comment: Are you trying to take 10 random records from the `Persons` table?

Comment: The only way that query runs as fast as it does is because of modern hardware. The query above requires a full table scan. Yes, sql server on a fair machine can scan. However, you are might want to make use of the TOP command or use a partion function to rank order the results. The way you have it, every record has to be serialized by the newid function and then only the top 10 returned.